# Buscar más de un patrón con expresiones regulares

Tags: python, regex

Estoy practicando las expresiones regulares en python y entonces para practicar bien decidí hacer un ejercicio en donde, como yo las llamo, busco "etiquetas normales" para pasarlas a html. Ejemplo: lo que estoy buscando es que, por ejemplo, si tengo un texto que diga `<color:red>Texto<>`, quiero que ese texto lo devuelva como `<p style="color:red">Texto</p>` y hasta ahora como lo he hecho me ha funcionado, por lo que este es mi código:

```
import re
import sys

final_text = re.sub(r"\<color\:(\w*)\>(.*)\<\>", r"<p style='color:\1'>\2</p>", sys.argv[1])

print(final_text)
```

Quiero decir que este código python lo ejecuto desde php por lo que de esa forma paso los datos, pero ahora tengo una duda la cual honestamente no tengo idea de cómo resolver, la cual es ¿cómo puedo hacer para que mi expresión regular busque más de un patrón? Ejemplo: imaginemos que ahora ya tengo todas las etiquetas `<color:red><>` con su  respectivo color, (en mi caso el rojo) pero ahora quiero que si el texto tiene `<h1:green><>` y lo que quiero hacer es que python lo devuelva como `<h1 style="color:green"></h1>`, pero si tiene ambas que devuelva ambas, o si tiene una que devuelva solo una.

He buscado en internet pero creo que mi caso es un poco mas específico de lo que suele haber en internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes expandir tu código usando una *tabla* de sustituciones como esta:

```
sustituciones = [
    (r"\<color\:(\w*)\>(.*)\<\>", r"<p style='color:\1'>\2</p>"),
    (r"\<h(\d)\:(\w*)\>(.*)\<\>", r"<h\1 style='color:\2'>\3<(/p)>")
]
```

La tabla es en realidad una lista de tuplas. Cada tupla `(patron, reemplazo)` tiene una expresión regular y el reemplazo a aplicar cuando se cumple la expresión.

Con eso, sólo resta iterar aplicando cada tupla al texto ingresado:

```
for patron, reemplazo in sustituciones:
    texto = re.sub(patron, reemplazo, texto)
```

#### Demo

```
import re

sustituciones = [
    (r"\<color\:(\w*)\>(.*)\<\>", r"<p style='color:\1'>\2</p>"),
    (r"\<h(\d)\:(\w*)\>(.*)\<\>", r"<h\1 style='color:\2'>\3<(/p)>")
]

texto = "<color:red>Importante<><h2:green>titulo<>"

for patron, reemplazo in sustituciones:
    texto = re.sub(patron, reemplazo, texto)

print(texto)
```

produce:

```
<p style='color:red'>Importante<><h2:green>titulo</p>

Process finished with exit code 0
```